# LEFT OUTER JOIN error for subquery with hard coded value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, left-join

I am getting the following error in BigQuery, and do not understand how to fix it: "LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join."

My query looks something like the below:

```
WITH salesData AS (
  SELECT
    account_id,
    date,
    amount   
  FROM
    table1
), categoryData AS (  
  SELECT
    'Category1' AS category,
    SPLIT(accountIds, '|') AS accountIds,
    name,
    startDate,
    endDate
  FROM
    table2
)
SELECT
  salesData.*,
  (
    SELECT
      name
    FROM
      categoryData
    WHERE
      salesData.date >= startDate
    AND
      salesData.date <= endDate
    AND
      salesData.account_id IN UNNEST(accountIds)
  ) AS client_name,
  (
    SELECT
      category
    FROM
      categoryData
    WHERE
      salesData.date >= startDate
    AND
      salesData.date <= endDate
    AND
      salesData.account_id IN UNNEST(accountIds)
  ) AS category,
FROM
  salesData
```

Here the first table, `table1`, contains data about a series of transactions, where the `account_id` field represents the account the sale is credited to.

The second table, `table2`, contains data about those accounts - this data changes over time, so each record has an associated start and end date - the period where the associated data is valid for. Each record potentially applies to multiple accounts, so the field `accountIds` takes the form of pipe-separated IDs.

I need to match up data from `table2` to the transactions in `table1` by finding the corresponding row where the account ID is present in the pipe-separated string and where the transaction date falls between the start and end date.

I have approached this by using subqueries which allow me to apply these conditions, and this works fine for selecting most fields from `table2`. However, when I try to select the `category` field (which is hard-coded in my `WITH` statement` I get the error about the left outer join.

I need to have this hard coded value the query in `categoryData` will expand to be a UNION of multiple tables with a different category value for each.

What is causing this error, and how can I fix it? Or is there a better way to approach in general?

EDIT: Adding sample data.

Table1:

[image]

Table2:

[image]

Desired Results:

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  You could probably also simplify the query to focus on the error you want to fix.

Comment: I think this is as simple as I can make it to give full content, but have added some sample data.

Comment: this query returns error about left join? or you get this error from another query. In my cases when I got this error I had to rewrite query to cross join and then use where to filter only rows you want

Answer (score 0):

I believe your correlated subqueries are functioning as a left join, and because you are comparing dates with `>=` and `<=` (inequalities), you are seeing this error message.

I would approach the problem like this:

```
with salesData as (
  select account_id, date, amount from table1
),
categoryData as (
  select 'Category1' as category, account_id, name, startDate, endDate
  from table2
  left join unnest(split(accountIDs,'|')) account_id
)
select
  account_id,
  date,
  amount,
  name,
  category
from salesData
left join categoryData using(account_id)
where date between startDate and endDate
```

Also, I think your `table2` has overlapping start/end dates for `941|974|072`